Slow wifi recovers speed temporarily when reconnected
I have an IBM T420 running Ubuntu 24.04.
The wifi acts weird: Over time it slows to a crawl, but if I
disconnect and reconnect then the speed recovers to the expected
speed.
This is not a fluke: You might expect the wifi or my internet
connection to be overloaded now and then, but this is reproducible.
It sometimes recovers the speed by itself, but it is reproducible: Any
time it is slow, simply reconnect wifi and the speed recovers.
I did this timeout 10 tcpdump -ni all before and after reconnecting
wifi.
Note how the maximal time between packets is huge in the slow
situation (number in ms since last packet):
$ grep -v lo tcpdump.slow.txt |
    perl -pe 's/://g; s/^(\S+)/($1-$last)*1000/e;$last=$1;s/win.*//' |
sort -n | head -n -1 | tail
138.347000000067 wlp3s0 Out IP 192.168.100.133.53472 > 192.168.100.1.53 16660+ [1au] A? www.youtube.com. (44)
143.536000003223 wlp3s0 In  IP 91.189.91.42.443 > 192.168.100.133.41830 Flags [.], seq 3920040600, ack 1, 
145.438999999897 wlp3s0 In  IP 172.217.145.198.443 > 192.168.100.133.33518 Flags [.], seq 217117218513, ack 4, 
161.396000010427 wlp3s0 In  IP 91.189.91.42.443 > 192.168.100.133.41830 Flags [.], seq 1400015400, ack 1, 
163.872000004631 wlp3s0 In  IP 172.217.145.198.443 > 192.168.100.133.33518 Flags [.], seq 9287394269, ack 4, 
209.784000006039 wlp3s0 In  IP 172.217.145.198.443 > 192.168.100.133.33518 Flags [P.], seq 4401345409, ack 4, 
230.691000004299 wlp3s0 In  IP 91.189.91.42.443 > 192.168.100.133.41830 Flags [.], seq 42949602964294961696, ack 1, 
239.476000002469 wlp3s0 In  IP 172.217.145.198.443 > 192.168.100.133.33518 Flags [.], seq 2028121677, ack 4, 
244.7780000075 wlp3s0 In  IP 91.189.91.42.443 > 192.168.100.133.41830 Flags [.], seq 1540016800, ack 1, 
453.129999994417 wlp3s0 In  IP 91.189.91.42.443 > 192.168.100.133.41830 Flags [.], seq 23102893132310290713, ack 3045969685, 

But small in the fast situation:
$ grep -v lo tcpdump.fast.txt |
    perl -pe 's/://g; s/^(\S+)/($1-$last)*1000/e;$last=$1;s/win.*//' |
sort -n | head -n -1 | tail
14.2179999966174 wlp3s0 In  IP 122.2.214.142.443 > 192.168.100.133.48242 Flags [F.], seq 205202, ack 1933, 
14.4089999957941 wlp3s0 In  IP 91.189.91.42.443 > 192.168.100.133.41830 Flags [.], seq 7000071400, ack 1, 
15.348000000813 wlp3s0 In  IP 91.189.91.42.443 > 192.168.100.133.41830 Flags [.], seq 922600924000, ack 1, 
15.8539999974892 wlp3s0 In  IP 122.2.214.142.443 > 192.168.100.133.48218 Flags [.], ack 1931, 
18.1480000028387 wlp3s0 In  IP 202.138.160.143.443 > 192.168.100.133.58298 Flags [.], seq 131932133332, ack 1936, 
19.9160000047414 wlp3s0 In  IP 122.2.214.142.443 > 192.168.100.133.48262 Flags [.], seq 3640537805, ack 1932, 
24.6269999915967 wlp3s0 In  IP 91.189.91.42.443 > 192.168.100.133.41830 Flags [.], seq 1960021000, ack 1, 
29.4679999933578 wlp3s0 In  IP 202.138.160.143.443 > 192.168.100.133.56522 Flags [F.], seq 5944, ack 1936, 
33.2009999983711 wlp3s0 In  IP 202.138.160.143.443 > 192.168.100.133.56522 Flags [.], ack 1936, 
120.297000001301 wlp3s0 In  IP 202.138.160.143.443 > 192.168.100.133.56522 Flags [P.], seq 42014531, ack 518, 

What causes this?
https://git.data.coop/tange/Test/src/branch/main/slow-wifi
dmesg.txt

dmesg entries when reconnecting wifi

iwconfig.txt

ifconfig -a

lspci.txt:

lscpi

lsusb.txt

lsusb

uname:

uname -a

tcpdump.slow.txt:

Download big YouTube videos
Wait until wifi is slow
timeout 10 tcpdump -ni all
884 packets

tcpdump.fast.txt:

Continue downloading big YouTube videos
Disconnect and reconnect wifi (done immediately after slow)
timeout 10 tcpdump -ni all
32029 packets

Edit:
I happened to have a USB-wifi card. If I use that instead of the built-in card, I do not see the problem. So this seems to be linked to the wifi card - not the machine.

Is this a thing that only happens on a single network or on others, too? I must admit that I had my share of instable Wifi drivers (and firmware) situations, but whenever things started to crawl, it was some plastic-y router appliance being overtasked (betting on full memory due to routing tables, but who knows what happens inside these…)

btw, your forgejo is giving me a HTTP404; your probably needs visibilty settinsg?

The PHY has more than a dozen modulation schemes to choose from. Your station and the WAP dynamically negotiate an index based on current channel interference and noise conditions. Tell us about index and about RSSI received signal strength indication.

@MarcusMüller More networks. (Fixed Forgejo).

@J_H Which command do you want me to run?

The index dictates bits-per-second transmit speed. On my Mac I lean on the CMD key while clicking the WiFi icon. Under Linux I imagine it may correspond to viewing a /proc/net file, or grepping dmesg with suitable logging verbosity. Alternatively, ask your WAP about channels it is using.
